# How to enable the Function Keys to work in Android Studios emulator?

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to capture keyboard input in Android through the AVD Emulator all the keys work except for the Function Keys. When I press the Function keys nothing happens except opening the help menu with F1. The onKeyDown event doesn't even fire. How do I enable them and how do I prevent the help menu from appearing when pressing F1 if I can enable the Function keys?

```
   public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
       Log.e("Key", String.valueOf(event.getKeyCode()));
       switch (keyCode) {
           case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_F1:
               Log.e("Key", "F1 Pressed.");
           case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_F2:
               Log.e("Key", "F2 Pressed");
           default:
               Log.e("Key", String.valueOf(event.getKeyCode()));
               return super.onKeyUp(keyCode, event);
       }
   }
```

Thank you!

Comment: I would suppose the function key is captured by Windows and consumed before it can even reach the AVD, have you tried using a separate keyboard (like one of those Bluetooth ones) on an actual device and see what happens?

Comment: I haven't tried that yet.  I will give that a shot. Thank you.